# Amazon SES emails sent but undelivered

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have a Node.js back-end that sends out emails using the Amazon SES API. I have a verified domain and email address, and am able to send test emails from SES. I tested my integration with sending programmatically to three test gmail accounts, with the following results:

- Checking the email params, everything looks good
- None of the send emails are rejected by SES, as I get a confirmation id and message id in the response
- SES dashboard shows the daily emails sent increase after each message sent
- I do not see any send, render, or bounce errors in AWS Cloudwatch
- About 1 of 10 emails make it to the test accounts, and typically ~12 hours later.
- No code that would effect email parameters has been changed (to the best of my knowledge)

I have yet to look into whether this is related to the new bulk sender changes in Gmail, but those are coming in February, so not sure if it is related.

Any thoughts on where else the hickup could be?